# Trying to upgrade to v3. Unable to find 'admin' username for logging into mysagepay

Tags: opayo

I am the web developer for a company who need to upgrade to v3 of mysagepay to continue trading.

However, the only username that I have been given, does not appear to give me admin rights in the control panel. I need to add the IP address of our shopping cart provider to allow it to continue to work after the end of the july.

My guess is that there is another username , which is the full admin rights one..

The one I have is payments, which allows you to view orders etc, but not access most of the settings.

Is there a standard username for the admin account on a given vendor name? I've tried 'retrieve username' using various emails of the company, but they only return the payments username, which isn't apparently an admin user.

I've filled out a couple of forms for online support but as yet have had no useful responses, and time is running out.

Can any one advise as to whether there is a standard username that gives full access rights (admin?) or whether there is a way of telling what the admin user is.

Many Thanks - pulling my hair out here.

Gavin

Comment: [See this](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/16/38/administration-user-password). This seems like something you should take up with the person in your company who created the accounts, not us.

Answer (score 0):

Call Sage Pay. They can add the IP for you, and/or probably sort out an admin user account. You'll probably need your Merchant number in order to prove you have something to do with that vendor account - you can get this from the authorisation details screen when viewing one of the payments that you have. Number is 0845 111 4455 - I recommend calling out of core business hours as they are pretty busy then (but phones are manned 24/7)